# Punctuation of possessive quotations

Tags: punctuation, quotes

I believe that these five sentences may be correctly punctuated. Do you agree? I'm using quotes around the movie title (as *The New Yorker* does) instead of italics. Although it may be ugly, I’m banking on all punctuation as being correct. Please, no suggested recasts. I thank you for any feedback.

> 1. He said, “I thought I heard Judy say, ‘ “Gone with the Wind” ’s cast was unparalleled.’ ”
> 2. Joe said, “ ‘Gone with the 
>      Wind’ ’s cast was unparalleled.”
> 3. “Gone with the Wind” ’s cast was unparalleled.
> 4. “ ‘Gone with the Wind’ ’s cast was unparalleled,” Joe said.
> 5. Joe said “I thought I heard Judy say, ‘It was "Gone with the Wind” ’s’.”

Comment: The *New Yorker*'s punctuation (and, indeed, Use of English in general) is idiosyncratic. Just use the customary italics for titles.

Comment: Full spaces between quotes or before an apostrophe is not something I have seen before. Not even in French.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: It's idiosyncratic on the computer, but if you're writing it by hand, it's important to know the rule. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed ugly, and technically, I'd say you're within your [rights](http://www.ergonis.com/products/tips/punctuation-apostrophes-quotation-marks.php) to write your sentences that way. Having said that, I'll side with [George Bernard Shaw's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Superfluous_apostrophes_.28.22greengrocers.27_apostrophes.22.29) criticism of apostrophes as "uncouth bacilli". I think your sentences are replete with uncouth bacilli, for the sake of someone's (whose?) propriety.

I would not jump through the hoops of punctuation as you've done. I would hope common sense would allow rewrites as follows:

> He said, “I thought I heard Judy say, ‘“Gone with the Wind's” cast was unparalleled.’”
>   Joe said, “'Gone with the Wind’s' cast was unparalleled.”
>   “Gone with the Wind's” cast was unparalleled.
>   “‘Gone with the Wind’s' cast was unparalleled,” Joe said.
>   Joe said “I thought I heard Judy say, ‘It was "Gone with the Wind’s’.”

There is no space between double and single quotation marks.

James Harbeck [writes](http://theweek.com/article/index/249725/kill-the-apostrophe)

> Many apostrophes are really only there for condescension. Apostrophes do have one consistent function: The grammar griper brigade likes to use them as the tips on their cats-o-nine-tails. Theyre excellent tools for condescension. Dont tell me theres no classism in terms like "greengrocers apostrophe" (for apostrophes in plurals). Such agitation over a little mark that conveys nothing new — other, evidently, than, "This person doesnt know how to use apostrophes." Its a fashion infraction on the level of wearing white after Labor Day or socks with sandals.

[Should the Apostrophe Be Abolished?](http://grammar.about.com/od/punctuationandmechanics/a/Should-The-Apostrophe-Be-Abolished.htm)

“England and America are two countries separated by a common language.” -George Bernard Shaw

Comment: If 'common sense' were to prevail at all surely you would say 'the cast from/of "Gone with the Wind". If the French can manage perfectly well without a possessive case all of the time, why can't we simply abandon it when the interests of clear auditory amenity dictate.

Comment: @WS2 - I've spoken French all my life, and never even noticed that what you've stated is correct. I had to think through several possessive phrases to come to terms with that. The degree to which we take a native language for granted is stunning.